# C++ ResultSet rowCount

Tags: oracle, c++

Здравствуйте.
Подключился к серверу, выполнил запрос, через ResultSet::rs->next() перебираю все значения. Всё работает в целом.

Как мне без перебирания узнать количество строк? про "select count(*)..." знаю, но это совершенно не то. Мне нужно узнать количество строк в уже вернувшемся запросе.

Result::rs->getNumArrayRows() возвращает 0, всегда.

Работаю через OCCI, компилю GCC'ом в Ubuntu'е 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, это невозможно.

Вот если бы можно было воспользоваться связкой PL/SQL и вашего функционала на C++, было бы круто... И Google сказал, это возможно:

- Здесь работа с коллекциями: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10778/objects.htm#sthref340
- Здесь -- их атрибуты: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10778/metadata.htm#sthref595

Т.е. в чём заключается решение. Заполнение т.н. массивов выполняется на сервере Oracle через курсоры и коллекции, **`select` не используется**. У коллекции/массива есть свойство `count`, которое, похоже, в интерпретации OCCI является атрибутом `ATTR_NUM_ELEMENTS`. Вот его вы и смогли бы использовать, если переписали бы имеющийся функционал.